# insert order of in Many-to-Many Database Relationships with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to follow the tutorial from

[Many-to-Many Database Relationships with Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-many-to-many-database-relationships-with-flask-sqlalchemy)

in step2, it use a init_db.py to add some data into DB

I see that the order that post item is added to DB as

`db.session.add_all([post1, post2, post3])`

then it use flask shell to query from DB

```
Post The First [<Tag "animals">, <Tag "writing">]
```

```
Post The Third [<Tag "cooking">, <Tag "tech">, <Tag "writing">]
```

```
Post The Second []
```

```
`
```

I can see that post3 is using the id 2 in post table in db as in below image,

[image]

seems to me with

`db.session.add_all([post1, post2, post3])`

don't understand why post3 is inserted after post1?

I reproduced this in my laptop on sqlite and postgres, cannot figured out from sqlalchemy doc on session.add_all method can you help to review on it if I missed anything ?

Comment: however, if I give a session.commit() right after session.add_all(), the post order in DB is good
for example:
`
db.session.add_all([post1, post2, post3])
db.session.commit()
`

Comment: The session uses a graph structure to determine the order in which statements are sent to the database. In this case, _possibly_ the session decided to insert the first the tags, then associated posts and finally posts with no tags.  Or perhaps there was some other reason.  Generally, _it doesn't matter_.  Primary keys like `id` are best thought of as _labels_. The fact that they are numbers should be ignored.  If you want to be able to order them in order of insertion add a timestamp column and use it to order your queries.